# Closed form solution of $T(n) = 5T(n-1) + n^2$

Tags: recurrence-relation

How to find the closed form solution of this equation? Is there a repeatable pattern for solving this equation?

$$T(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n = 1\\
5T(n-1) + n^2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

> How to find the closed form solution of this equation?

This is linear nonhomogeneous recurrence relation of the form $a_n = a_n^{h}+a_n^{p}$ where former expression in the right hand side is homogeneous solution while later one particular. Now, $a_n^p$ becomes $p_2n^2+p_1n+p_0$ whereas $a_n^h$ becomes $\alpha5^n$. Now solve them.

Another straightforward approach is to recursively solve the equation as follows 
$$\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 5\cdot T(n-1)+n^2 \\
     &= 5[5\cdot T(n-2)+(n-1)^2]+n^2 \\
     &= 5^2T(n-2)+5(n-1)^2 + n^2 \\ 
     &= 5^3T(n-3)+5^2(n-2)^2 + 5(n-1)^2 + n^2 \\
     & \vdots\\
     &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}5^{n-k}\cdot k^2
\end{align*}$$

> Is there a repeatable pattern for solving this equation?

The very word recurrence implies pattern.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that deducing the sum is pure extrapolation at this point. You would also need to prove it is equivalent to $T(n)$ by induction or some other method. Though, this is a minor detail and should be relatively trivial.

Comment: @ryan Do you mean this solution is not useful?

Comment: Not at all, the solution is entirely correct, but it is based on intuition, or pattern extrapolation. This is a good thing though, because the extrapolation gives us this "guess" for the summation, then we can formally prove equivalence between $T(n)$ and this sum with induction.

Comment: @ryan Your comment was dead on, but I'd argue that at the introduction level, it's anything but a *minor* detail.

Comment: @RickDecker that's fair too, maybe _minor detail_ was not the best description. My intent was to convey it is important, while proving it is usually not all that difficult, so it's often omitted. I typically omit it and say "this can be proven correct via induction, etc." I would agree though, at an introductory level, I would want to see the proof (if I were grading an assignment or something).

Comment: Plugging n=1 into this solution would yield T(1) = 0 where it should be T(1)=1. I believe k should go from 1 to n in the summation which solves this

Comment: Also you will not get the last value of n^2 when k=n-1 using this, but if k = n you do

Comment: @Trak $T(n-k)=T(1)=1$ so $k=n-1$